# hive date format error when used with the table

Tags: sql, hive

I have fields like date_column = 20140228 in the table 1. When I hard code the number like below it works, but when I specify the column name its failing. With error
H110 Unable to submit statement. Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 2:1 cannot recognize input near 'select' 'date_format' '(' in select clause [ERROR_STATUS]

```
Working:
    select date_format(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(cast('2014022817' as string),'yyyyMMddHH')),'yyyy-MM-dd HH');

Failing:
    select 
        select date_format(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(cast(date_column as string),'yyyyMMddHH')),'yyyy-MM-dd HH')
    from 
        table1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you repeating the `select`?  Try this:

```
select date_format(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(cast(date_column as string
                                                    ),'yyyyMMddHH'
                                               )
                                ),'yyyy-MM-dd HH'
                  )
from table1
```